# How to use props of a component out of the component in react with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

As i am new to react i have a question.I have a react component and its properties. And I want to reach one of these properties from the page where i used my component.

```
type BranchProps = {
  SelectedBranch : string
 }

class Branch extends React.Component<BranchProps, BranchState> {
    constructor(props: BranchProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SelectBox></SelectBox>
        )
    }
}

export default Branch ;
```

ParentPage.tsx

```
import Branch...
class Page extends.... {
    ctor..
    const test:string = () => {
        Branch.SelectedBranch ???
    }
}
```

And i want to get "SelectedBranch" from my ParentPage.
Note: SelectedBranch is changing on change event. Should i make my SelectedBranch a const and export it or what should i do ?

Comment: That isn't possible in React, everything has a downward data flow. If you want to have data accessible globally, look into having a global state object

Comment: Or lift the state one level up so both `Page` and `Branch` pull data from one source.

Answer (score 0):

I have created this Input.js child component with different props

```
const Input = ({ placeholder, label, value, onChangeText, secureTextEntry }) => {

return (
    <View >
        <Text >{ label }</Text>
        <TextInput
            secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            autoCorrect={false}
            value={value}
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
            style={inputStyles} 
        />
    </View>
);
};
```

Once I import it to be used on a page, this is how the manipulation of the content is being done. the value is been passed on by simply quoting the specific prop

```
<Input 
        secureTextEntry
        placeholder={'password'}
        label={'Password'}
        value={this.state.password}
        onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
/>
```

Here the 'password' is been assigned to the component by using the state of the parent. something like this, you can assign the value as you see fit.

```
state = { email: '', password: '', error: '', loading: false };
```

A far better way exist by using the Redux approach. would be advisable to have a look.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, you should understand the difference between `state` and `props` inside a component. Props shouldn't be updated, it's the state's role.

You can't directly access component's props outside of it.

In pure react (without librabry like [redux](https://redux.js.org/)) the right way should be to use callbacks to return the element to the parent.

```js
class Branch extends React.Component<BranchProps, BranchState> {
    state = {
      'selectedBranch': ''
    }
    
    constructor(props: BranchProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    handleOnChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({'selectedBranch': e.target.value})
      
      this.props.parentHandleChangeBranch(this.state.selectedBranch);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <SelectBox value={this.state.selectedBranch} onChange="{this.handleOnChange}"></SelectBox>
        )
    }
}

class Page extends React.Component {

  state = {
    'branch': null
  }
  
  parentHandleChangeBranch  = (branch) => {
    this.setState({'branch': branch};
  }
  
  render () {
    <div>
      <Branch parentHandleChangeBranch={this.parentHandleChangeBranch} />
    </div>
  }
}
```

You can declare a function in the parent component and pass it as `prop` to the child. Then, call this callback whenever you want inside the child.

Comment: we would all appreciate a more collaborative and welcoming wording. Then, please, note that the OP is a bit different... `how to use props from a component outside of it?`

Comment: ok lets say it is not a prop it is just a variable. like 
export let SelectedBranch : string = "Branch1";
and Cant i import this like 
import * as Branch from Branch;
Branch.SelectedBranch ?

Comment: @Egomen You can't access Component's elements from outside. If you want your Page component  aware about the selectedBranch update, you have to set a new state in it.

Comment: @Egomen In other way, I've probably missunderstood your needs but you can take a look about refs : https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components

Comment: @JulienBourdic I just want to get the Variable value from child component with ref i will be able to reach all dom, and i dont need this.